# slideToggle() not exanding in mobile view

Tags: jquery, mobile, slidetoggle

I am trying to make a div expand show to hidden content using slideToggle(). 
it is working fine in the desktop version but when i resize it to mobile view. The content slides, but the div is not expanding to show the content

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/freal0s/w02ctpem/`
```

this is the html

```
    <div id="our-team">
  <div class="row item active">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="single-member"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="team member" />
        <h4>Name 1</h4>
        <h5>Chairman </h5>
        <div class="btn btn-more">more</div>
        <p class="team-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec mi in mauris aliquam elementum vitae ac libero. Proin in ornare enim. Mauris neque urna, consectetur a hendrerit ac, pulvinar ut leo. Nunc id tellus laoreet, rutrum risus vitae,
          vestibulum tortor. Mauris semper hendrerit posuere. Maecenas vulputate</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="single-member"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="team member" />
        <h4>Name 1</h4>
        <h5>Chairman </h5>
        <div class="btn btn-more">more</div>
        <p class="team-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec mi in mauris aliquam elementum vitae ac libero. Proin in ornare enim. Mauris neque urna, consectetur a hendrerit ac, pulvinar ut leo. Nunc id tellus laoreet, rutrum risus vitae,
          vestibulum tortor. Mauris semper hendrerit posuere. Maecenas vulputate</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the css

```
#our-team {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  color: #43484E;
}

#our-team h2 {
  color: #43484E;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

#our-team .team-members {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 55px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden
}

#our-team .btn-more {
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #43484e;
  margin: 0;
}

#our-team .team-desc {
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#our-team .btn-more:hover {
  background-color: #43484e;
  color: #ffdd15;
}

#our-team .single-member {
  min-height: 375px;
}

.single-member {
  background-color: #ffdd15;
  border: 1px solid #ffdd15;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.single-member img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.single-member h4,
.single-member h5 {
  text-align: center
}
```

the jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("p.team-desc").hide();

    $(".btn-more").click(function() {
      $(this).closest('.single-member').find('.team-desc').slideToggle();
    });
  });
```

the team-desc div is expanding on the desktop version but when i resize the view. the team-desc div is not expanding.

Comment: cant reproduce problem, your code is working on any viewport size

Comment: try looking at my site

pitiscoin.com

it's at the our team section

Comment: Please include the logic needed to replicate your problem on site.  Asking questions restricts you from only linking to off site paste sites for a reason, as detailed in the how to ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: but it is working on the fiddle, but it's not working on the site.

Answer (score 0):

```
//responsive.css:22    
@media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px)   
.single-member {
    height: 515px; // << here is your problem
```